# Rebus MSMQ appears to be losing messages

Tags: rebus

I have followed the pub/sub demo with msmq and am loosing messages when the publisher is started before the subscribers. The msmq has already been created.

**My Publisher code in one console app**

```
 _activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator();

Configure.With(_activator)
            .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq("PaymentsToTake"))
            .Subscriptions(s => s.StoreInMemory())
            .Start();

/* In the timer code */
MyDateMessage m = new MyDateMessage()
        {
            NowTime = DateTime.Now,
            Counter = _index
        };

_activator.Bus.Publish(m).Wait();
_index++;
```

**My Subscriber Code in another console app**

```
_activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator();

_activator.Register(() => new PrintDateTime());


Configure.With(_activator)
            .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq("PaymentsToTake-Receiver1"))
            .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().Map<MyDateMessage>("PaymentsToTake"))
            .Start();

_activator.Bus.Subscribe<MyDateMessage>().Wait();
```

**Results**
When I run the subscriber, I get the message Sending MyDateMessage ->  and then when I run the consumer, the first message that comes up is "53 The time is" hence messages 0-52 were lost!

Comment: Hi Flash, I have answered your question - could you try and see if it fixes your problem? And if so, please mark the question as answered (and if not: Please tell me, so I can help you :) )

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because you are using the *in-mem subscription storage*, meaning that the publisher does NOT remember who subscribed when it was previously running.

For most (if not all) real-world scenarios, you should choose some kind of persistent storage for subscriptions. It could be a database like SQL Server, or it could even be a local JSON file.

You just need to change the line

```
.Subscriptions(s => s.StoreInMemory())
```

into something like e.g.

```
.Subscriptions(s => s.UseJsonFile(@"subscriptions.json"))
```

Could you try and see if that fixes your problem? :)

Comment: Thanks Mookid. After further testing with MSMQ, I might end up just using RabitMQ instead as seems to "just work".

Comment: Yes - RabbitMQ is capable of doing proper multicast, which Rebus can leverage by using it as its subscription storage. As you have observed, that relieves you of the burden of persisting subscriptions. Happy messaging! :)